# 1 of 3 Windows PCs on home network can't access shares

Tags: windows-10, networking

I have a home network, with a ZyXel NAS drive. On this network, 2 Windows 10 PCs can access various shares, including on the NAS. But one Windows 10 Pro PC, cannot access any network shares.

If I issue a Net use command (with IP or hostname):

```
C:\Users\Mario>net use P: \\nasdevice\share
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

When using Explorer, I get the message:

```
Network Error

Windows cannot access \\nasdevice\share

Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.

[Expanded Information]

Error code: 0x80004005
Unspecified error

Network error share cannot access 0x80004005
I see no additional information in the event logs.
```

I can however ping the NAS device, and access it's web browser control panel from the problematic PC.

I have tried the following:

- Insured the NAS share is accessible from other computers
- Verified all computers have the same time
- Applied all current Windows updates.
- Turned off Windows Firewall (and back on)
- Turned on SMB 1.0/CIFS Client in features
- Turned off SMB 1.0/CIFS Client in features
- Insured that SMB Direct was enabled in Features
- Turned on Network Discovery
- Turned on file and printer sharing (don't think that's needed, but I did)
- Even enabled the 'Enable insecure guest logons' in Group Policy
- Rebooted numerous times

I set all these services to automatic startup:

- Function Discovery Provider Host (was manual)
- Function Discovery Resource Publication (was Manual triggered)
- SSDP Discovery
- UPnP Device Host
- TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper

In Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center, Change adapter settings, I changed Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) > Advanced > Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP on the WINS (checked).

So now I'm ready to toss this and reinstall Windows 10, except that I know it will take a complete day to reinstall my software and preferences.

The network is all on a Netgear R6230 router. Devices use DHCP, which is provided by the Netgear router.  The IP address range is 10.0.0.x, the problem workstation is 10.0.0.25, a working workstation is 10.0.0.36, and the NAS device is 10.0.0.31. The DNS is setup through DHCP, which comes from that NetGear router, so the device is pingable by its name from all devices.

"nslookup nasdevice" reveals the same on all machines (working or not): server: [www.routerlogin.com](http://www.routerlogin.com) Address: 10.0.0.1 *** [www.routerlogin.com](http://www.routerlogin.com) can't find nasdevice: Non-existant domain

But again, all 3 PCs can ping by the NAS by name, but only 1 PC can't access the share.

Any ideas on why this one PC can't access the same shares 2 others can?

Note: This question was closed on Server Fault, so I'm reposting here.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my DNS client service was disabled, and not running.  Not just that, it was also grayed out, and I could not alter it.

I wound up changing a registry setting of
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Start` and changed it from 4 to 2, and rebooted.

The DNS client is now running, and my problematic PC can now access the network share.

I read somewhere that Windows update 2004 may have introduced this change.  Don't know.